# Remove notification observer from another view controller

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

Hi I am developing Iphone application in which  am registering one notification observer for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification. Now I want to remove that one from another view controller. My code looks like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(applicationBecomeActive)
 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
 object:nil];
```

And I am creating one method for removing observer:

```
-(void) removeObserver
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; 
}
```

and I am calling this method from other view controller but its not working. I think I have to store observer. But I don't know how to do this. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: So you have two view controllers. You add view controller one as an observer for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and you want to remove the observer in the view controller two. Is that correct?

Comment: @dasdom yeah exactly.

Comment: Is there any one have a answer for this ?

Comment: I think most of the Objective-C developers are learning Swift at the moment (as I do). :)

Answer (score 0):

The second view controller needs a reference to the instance of the first view controller. Let's assume it is hold in a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) FirstViewControler *firstViewController;
```

Then your code to remove the fist view controller as an observer would look like this:

```
- (void)removeObserver
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.firstViewController]; 
}
```

The missing part is: You have to set the property somewhere. Where to do that depends on your code.

Comment: I will try this and let you know whether works or not :)