# Removing a notification observer from another viewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 ViewControllers VCA and VCB. I have an observer in VCA set up in viewDidAppear

I navigate from VCA to VCB and then when you press a button on VCB the notification is posted which performs some function
then I dismiss VCB and VCA appears again

```
//VCB 

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:    Notification.Name("name"), object: nil)
}

 @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

//VCA

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.someFunction), name: Notification.Name("name"), object: nil)
}
```

Now the problem is as soon as VCA appears it adds another observer
I get that the problem is I need to remove the Observer but if I remove it in viewWillDisappear , the notification never get called because it is removed before I can post it

I tried to remove the observer in VCB like so

```
    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCA") as! VCA
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(vc, name: Notification.Name("stateChange"), object: nil)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

But that didn't work

So I need to remove observer in VCA from VCB when dismissing VCB.
I have looked at [Remove notification observer from another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998145/remove-notification-observer-from-another-view-controller) already

But it is in OBJC and I didn't understand it exactly , plus the OP hasn't marked it as correct solution or commented that it did work

Comment: Add the observer in 'viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** it's better here to set a delegate instead of notification center as the latter is used for 1-M not 1-1 notify

**Second** You can add the observer inside `viewDidLoad`

if you need to remove it after dismiss of vcB then end of the function `someFunction` do

```
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !. How would I go about using the delegate in this case?
Also If I add it at the end of  "someFunction" then the notification would only be posted once. I want the notification to be posted each time user presses the button

Comment: check https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/   if so then leave it don't remove the observer or add it again inside the action that goes to vcB

Comment: If I don't remove the observer , the notification get posted multiple times on each press if I went back and forth between the view controllers

But thanks for your answer, I checked out delegates and they solved this problem